# the encoding issues about match locale in openGauss

Tags: encoding, open-gauss

First retrieve possible supported encodings using the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT pg_catalog.pg_encoding_to_char(conforencoding) FROM pg_catalog.pg_conversion;
```

Then create the databases using encodings from the previous list

```
CREATE DATABASE test_WIN1256 WITH ENCODING = 'WIN1256';
```

get the error

> ERROR:  encoding "WIN1256" does not match locale "en_US.UTF-8" DETAIL:
> The chosen LC_CTYPE setting requires encoding "UTF8".

How to deal with the error?

Answer (score 0):

you can set the LC_ALL in ~/.bashrc and ~/.profile files:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.utf-8
export LANG=en_US.utf-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.utf-8
```

and then source the .bashrc:

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

Verify set with locale command re-ran the install again.

You can also create the database with specific LC_CTYPE, like:

```
CREATE DATABASE test_WIN1256 WITH ENCODING 'WIN1256' \
 LC_CTYPE 'en_US.UTF-8' LC_COLLATE 'en_US.UTF-8';
```